# Como direccionar de un componente a otro mediante clic en botones en React

Tags: reactjs

> Quiero que de este componente home me direccione a otros componentes haciendo clic en los botones creados, pero no logro con algunos metodos que intente con Router, Link, etc.

```
import './Home.css';
import FotoPortada from '/Users/SAVAL/source/ProyectoFinal/src/assets/Imagenes/FotoPortada.png'
import FotoPerfil from '/Users/SAVAL/source/ProyectoFinal/src/assets/Imagenes/ImgUsuario.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faHouseChimney } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faEraser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faFileExcel } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faRightFromBracket } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



export function Home ({user, setUser}) {
    const handleLogout = () =>{
        setUser([])
            
    }

   


  
      
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" />
    return(
 
    <section className="Seccion">
        
        <img src={FotoPortada} width={Window} height={350}/>
        <img className="FotoPerfil" src={FotoPerfil}></img>
        <text className="NUsuario">{user}</text>
        <text className="Cargo">Gerente</text>
        <div>
        <button className="agregarUsuario" style={{backgroundColor:'#424BB2'}}>Agregar Usuario</button>
        <button className="EliminarUsuario" style={{backgroundColor:'#424BB2'}}>Eliminar Usuario</button>
        <button className="CerrarSesionH" onClick={handleLogout} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faRightFromBracket} style={{color: "#9297a0"}} /></button>
        </div>
        <div>
        <nav className="MenuBotones">
            <ul>
                
                    <Link to="/agregarMov" path='/agregarMov'>
                    <button className="add" ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} style={{color: "#9297a0",}} /></button>
                    </Link>
                

                    <Link to="/">
                    <button className="homeButt"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHouseChimney} style={{color: "#9297a0",}} /></button>
                    </Link>

                    <Link>
                    <button className="eraseMov"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEraser} style={{color: "#9297a0"}} /></button>
                    </Link>

                    <Link>
                    <button className="libros"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFileExcel} style={{color: "#9297a0"}} /></button>
                    </Link>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    )
}

export default Home
```

> Y quiero que me direccione a este otro componente al hacer clic en el boton add por ejemplo(los link son de otros métodos que intente para que me direccione)

```
import React from "react"
import "./AgregarMov.css"

export function AgregarMov(){

    return(
        <div>
            <h1 className="Mov">Movimientos</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AgregarMov
```

> Este seria el APP

```
import { Formulario } from '../Components/Formulario'
import { Home } from '../Components/Home'
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'



function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState([])

  return (

    <div className='App'>
      {
        !user.length > 0
          ? <Formulario setUser={setUser} />
          : <Home user={user} setUser={setUser} />
          
      }

    </div>
     
  )
}

export default App
```

> cabe recalcar que ya logre que me direccione desde un componente formulario de inicio de sesión a home, peor ya de home no logro que me direccione a otro componente